# What is a TACH LEAD?

Tags: ignition

What is a TACH LEAD on this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's the wire that goes to the tachometer to show you the RPM of the engine. It's one pulse per spark. You set the number of cylinders on tach and it's then divides by that number to display the RPM of the engine.